# Android Studio AGP upgrade assistant wants to upgrade to same version

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

I've been tasked to upgrade android existing project code to new version cause its failing to build. In the build error it states:

> Gradle sync failed: Namespace not specified. Please specify a
> namespace in the module's build.gradle file like so:          android {
> namespace 'com.example.namespace'           }           If the package attribute
> is specified in the source AndroidManifest.xml, it can be migrated
> automatically to the namespace value in the build.gradle file using
> the AGP Upgrade Assistant; please refer to
> https://developer.android.com/studio/build/agp-upgrade-assistant for
> more information. (1 s 677 ms)

but when doing the steps above, the assistant shows the following:

[image]

whith no option in the dropdown besides the 7.2.1
any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: I would expect that Android Studio first have to successfully load and sync your Gradle project, otherwise upgrade assistant will not work. So repairing by upgrading it will not work as far as I know.

Comment: @Robert thanks for the reply. When I sync the project is when it says that I need to run the AGP Upgrade Assistant. As I understand, the project is old and has different gradle structure, so I need to run the AGP upgrade assistant to update it, otherwise I can't sync.

Comment: I wouldn't call AGP 7.21 old, version 8.0 has been released in April 2023. I have seen projects using much older versions like 4.x or 5.x these AGP version are old. BTW. the message about setting namespace should be very easy o fix manually: Just set your package name (`applicationId` in gradle config) also as [namespace](https://developer.android.com/build/configure-app-module#set-namespace)

Comment: @Robert thanks for the help, I guess it was as you said, I fixed it by playing around with gradle versions (gradle+ gradle wrapper versions + compile/target Sdk), until it synced, after that I could do the AGP upgrade assistant, and after that.... they realized that someone else had already done the work months ago... at least I learned something. If you like please post it as an aswer so I can mark it as the solution.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Remove package element from manifest and insert it into build.gradle(:app) as namespace:

android {
...
...
namespace 'your.package.name'
}